# How can I rename location in radare2?

Tags: radare2

In radare2 I would like to be able to rename a node in the graph view. I though setting a flag to the entry of the graph node would also change its title, but the address of the nodes still shows instead.

How can I set the name based on the flag?
Thanks for any help.